# PHP - How to echo a variable that contains php?

Tags: php, echo

If I have a piece of code that reads a chunk of HTML from a txt file and then echos that html onto the page, how can I accomplish the same task, but when there is PHP inside of the txt file?

ex:

this is the file being read:

```
<?php 
$filecontent = // read some other file
echo($filecontent);
?>
```

and this is the page that is reading the file:

```
<?php
$code1 = //reading the above file
?>
<html>
<?php echo($code1); ?>
</html>
```

Comment: `echo` is a language construct and does not require parentheses.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary well when i started learning, the guy i was watching did it, and its just become a habit.  It works nonetheless

Comment: I would recommend using an [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) statement instead.

Comment: Just cause *the guy* did it doesn't make it right. Too many bad habits in the PHP community. Help clean it up.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary: This is a religious argument.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary it has no negative effects, and it makes your code a lot more readable.

Comment: @nife552, as Jon said, it's a religious argument. Zealots on both sides :)

Answer (score 2):

When you want to process files containing PHP code you need to use `include` instead of `echo`.

```
<?php include('your_php_file_name'); ?>
```

If you have the contents of the file in a string you are in a tough spot because the only way to process the code is `eval`, and in addition you have to properly set up any environment that the code requires. `eval` itself should be avoided, and the latter is impossible to do in the general case.

Comment: So why did you echo'ed it?

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo: Mistakes happen :-)

Comment: if there is html in addition to php in the file that is being read, how does that get handled?

Comment: @nife552: Exactly the way it's handled in the file doing the reading -- inside PHP tags code gets executed, outside them stuff is printed verbatim.

Answer (score 0):

Use include instead of echo:

```
<?php include($file_that_contains_php); ?>
```

Comment: `include` is a language construct and does not require parentheses.

Comment: Does not require, but it can be used. I always use it, mostly for readability.

Answer (score 0):

you need to include the first file and echo statement in the first file will get executed.

```
<html>
<?php require_once("firstfile.php"); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to echo htmlentities($code1), because when you echo  then browser will not show it contents, because it try to parse it as a html tag, but htmlentities will encode to safe html output this characters.
If you want to evaulate the code, then you need eval($code1) or include it.